# Python 3.4 (Anaconda) - MySQL connector

Tags: python, mysql, database, anaconda, connector

I installed Python 3.4 by installing Anaconda. Now I would like to read data out of a MySQL database from Python. Hence I tried installing the Connector/Python 2.0.3 (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python) for Python 3.4.

After it finishes downloading, it says "Python v3.4 not found". I looked it up online and came to the conclusion that something might be wrong with my environment variables. When copy pasting the location of IPython (in the Anaconda folder), i.e. C:\Users\Julie\Anaconda3\python.exe "C:\Users\Julie\Anaconda3\Scripts/ipython-script.py", as the PATH variable, I still get the same problem.

Does anybody know how to resolve this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: When you installed Anaconda did you check the box to make it your default Python 3.4?

Comment: @asmeurer I have no idea, but I'll install it again to make sure. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: @asmeurer, I reinstalled it and now it says nothing about python not being found. but when i type the following in python: import datetime import mysql.connector, it says "no module named mysql".

Comment: @asmeurer, I reinstalled it and now it says nothing about python not being found. but when i type the following in python: import datetime import mysql.connector, it says "no module named mysql". do you perhaps know how to solve this?

Answer (score 6):

First go to the location of your conda.exe, for me it's:

```
cd C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts
```

Then install the package:

```
conda.exe install mysql-connector-python
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem (except using 2.7).  The following solution worked.

http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/33i99j/does_anyone_know_how_to_install_mysqldb_with/

Basically go to your scripts directory within the anaconda directory and type the following into your command prompt: `conda.exe install mysql-python`

Answer (score 0):

PyMySQL does not support Python 3. Install [mysqlclient-python]
(https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python) instead:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev 
pip install mysqlclient
```